# Let $m$ be a positive integer. Prove that the dihedral group $D_{4m+2}$ of order $8m+4$ contains a subgroup of order 4.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $m$ be a positive integer. Prove that the dihedral group $D_{4m+2}$ of order $8m+4$ contains a subgroup of order 4.

Im fairly stumped as to where to start with this one, any input would be helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd prefer not to use the Sylow theorems, we can also see this simply because $4m + 2 = 2(2m + 1)$. That is, if we present $D_n$ as $D_n = \left<\sigma,\tau\mid\sigma^n = \tau^2 = 1, \tau\sigma\tau = \sigma^{-1}\right>$, then if $n = 2k$ is even, we have $2k$ "rotation" elements ($\sigma^i$, $i = 0, \ldots, 2k - 1$) and $2k$ "reflection" elements ($\sigma^i\tau$, $i = 0, \ldots, 2k - 1$), so we can take $H = \{e, \sigma^k, \tau, \sigma^k\tau\}$ as the subgroup of order $4$, which is easily verified to be a subgroup.

Comment: @Stahl I havent seen sylows theorem yet so this is of great help!

Answer (score 2):

Since it is of order $4(2m+1)$, it contains a Sylow-2-subgroup, of order =$4$.

> Edit:
>   The first Sylow-theorem states that, if $p^m$ is the highest power of $p$ which divides the order of $G$, then $G$ contains a subgroup of order $p^m$. In our case, the highest power of $2$ dividing the order of $G$ is simply $4$, hence the result.

Comment: Am I being ambiguous?

Comment: Your answer looks good to me. I've provided an alternative solution that works without Sylow theory, in case @bobdylan hasn't seen those theorems yet (although it assumes knowledge of a certain presentation of $D_n$).